# Is it possible to know the line on which an error occurred using try/except in Python?

Tags: python, exception

For example, is there anything that could be added to the following that could provide the line number of the error?

```
try:
    assert False
except Exception, e:
    # lineOfError = ?
    # print lineOfError
    print e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `traceback` module:

```
from sys import exc_info
from traceback import extract_tb

try:
    assert False
except Exception as e:
    print(extract_tb(exc_info()[2])[0][1])
    print(e)
```

Comment: The only difference I needed was an added [0] index in order to access the tuple containing the error information: `print(extract_tb(exc_info()[2])[0][1])`

Comment: @Phillip: Thanks for catching that.  It's fixed now.